# What is causing these wet spots on interior concrete walls during rain?

Tags: concrete, leak, wet

We had a roof leak, then a mold remediation. We parged the interior brick walls with concrete, then repointed the exterior brick.

During tonight's rain I'm getting damp spots on the interior concrete on the wall of the second floor, rear room. The spot on the far left is wet to the touch.

I assume this means the exterior pointing is missing spots, and water is getting in horizontally from outside through the brick.

But then why are the wet spots all nearly uniform in a horizontal line across the wall? Could this be coming straight down from the roof and then getting caught somewhere halfway down and soaking through?

I am hoping to identify the cause of the leak, and determine how serious it is.

[image]

Comment: Where are the wet spots relative to the ground level outside? You don't say if this is in a basement or higher floor. Masonry walls will generally absorb water that sticks around. What does your roof overhang look like outside of this area? What about gutters or grading?

Comment: Thank you; second floor, rear room. Flat roof with almost no overhang. Roof was recently replaced so flashing should be sound.

Comment: If you're missing mortar in horizontal rows between bricks, then it's quite likely that the water is moving horizontally through these gaps and seeping through the interior finish. Of course, it won't necessarily be in perfect horizontal lines, but water _will_ move through the path of least resistance. TBH, though, I'm not really sure exactly what it is that you're asking. Please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what it is that you'd like us to help you with.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post. I am hoping to identify the cause of the leak, and determine how serious it is.